# Python Socket Issues! (OSError: Errno 10035)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create a game using sockets. Each player can choose between Server and Client. Below is my code. If anyone could please help me get the sockets connected, it would be GREATLY appreciated. I am running into Error 10035 when trying to connect the Client to the Server. I have spent numerous hours trying to work out these problems, but I have been extremely unsuccessful.

UPDATE: Error 10035 is still appearing when I use `print(client.connect_ex((connection[1], 65355))` instead of `client.connect` and `client.sendto` under `phase = ["client", "searching"]`. I updated the code to reflect what I currently have.

```
import pygame, socket

#Presets
pygame.init()
size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
#screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Glyph Wars")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
end = False
connection = ["", ""]
IPNotFound = False
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 30, False, False)
click = False
phase = ["menu", ""]

#Functions
def x(scale):
    return size[0] * scale

def y(scale):
    return size[1] * scale

def display_button(text, output, x, y, w, h, color, tx, ty, click):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [x, y, w, h])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), [x, y, w, h], 5)
    screen.blit(font.render(text, False, (0, 0, 0)), [x + tx, y + ty])
    if (mpos[0] > x and mpos[0] < x + w) and (mpos[1] > y and mpos[1] < y + h) and click == True:
        phase[0] = output[0]
        phase[1] = output[1]
        click = False

def display_text(text, x, y, color):
    screen.blit(font.render(text, False, color), [x, y])

while end == False:

#Presets
    mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill((90, 90, 90))

#Controls
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            end = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.display.iconify()
            if phase == ["client", "typing"]:
                if event.key != pygame.K_BACKSPACE and event.key != pygame.K_RETURN:
                    connection[1] += event.unicode
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    connection[1] = connection[1][:-1]
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    IPNotFound = False
                    phase = ["client", "initiating"]

#Logic
    if phase == ["menu", ""]:
        display_button("Host Game", ["host", "initiating"], x(0.4), y(0.3), int(x(0.2)), int(y(0.05)), (10, 240, 210), x(0.06), y(0.005), click)
        display_button("Join Game", ["client", "typing"], x(0.4), y(0.4), x(0.2), y(0.05), (10, 240, 210), x(0.06), y(0.005), click)
    elif phase[0] == "host":
        if phase[1] == "initiating":
            server = socket.socket()
            server.setblocking(True)
            server.settimeout(1)
            serverlink = (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 65355)
            server.bind(serverlink)
            server.listen(3)
            phase[1] = "searching"
        elif phase[1] == "searching":
            display_text("Searching for players...", x(0.4), y(0.2), (0, 0, 0))
            display_text("IP: " + server.getsockname()[0] + ":" + str(server.getsockname()[1]), x(0.4), y(0.3), (255, 0, 0))
            try:
                connection[0], connection[1] = server.accept()
                connection[0].setblocking(True)
                server.sendto("connected".encode(), connection[1])
                phase[1] = "connected"
            except socket.timeout:
                pass
        elif phase[1] == "connected":
            display_text("Connected with " + connection[1], x(0.4), y(0.4), (0, 255, 0))
    elif phase[0] == "client":
        display_button(connection[1], ["client", "typing"], x(0.4), y(0.3), x(0.2), y(0.05), (130, 130, 130), x(0.005), y(0.005), click)
        if connection[1] == "":
            display_text("Enter IP", x(0.405), y(0.305), (65, 65, 65))
        if IPNotFound == True:
            display_text("Having difficulty finding IP...", x(0.4), y(0.4), (0, 0, 0))
        if phase[1] == "initiating":
            client = socket.socket()
            client.setblocking(True)
            client.settimeout(5)
            phase[1] = "searching"
        elif phase[1] == "searching":
            phase[1] = "typing"
            try:
                #print(client.connect_ex((connection[1], 65355)))
                client.connect((connection[1], 65355))
                client.sendto("connected".encode(), (connection[1], 65355))
                IPNotFound = False
                phase[1] = "connected"
            except socket.timeout:
                IPNotFound = True
        elif phase[1] == "connected":
            display_text("Connected with " + connection[1], x(0.4), y(0.4), (0, 255, 0))

#End
    click = False
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit
```

Comment: You are starting server with port `65535` and trying to connect client with port `65355`. They are different!!!

Comment: @arunp9294 I fixed this but still get Error 10035 upon running on two different machines. I feel dumb though for not noticing that...

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2

But you should first clarify where/when each error is triggered.
Also, I strongly suggest you write some simplified code for client/server sockets, you should find plenty of tutorials and blogs covering this.

PS : It looks like you're using TCP (socket stream), there are some caveats when trying to use TCP for message oriented exchanges, UDP might better suit your needs. (Otherwise, you should define an end of stream tag when sending data)

---

Quoting:

> **WSAEINVAL**
> 10022
>
> **Invalid argument.**
>
> Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not listening.

And:

> **WSAEWOULDBLOCK**
>
> 10035
>
> **Resource temporarily unavailable.**
>
> This error is returned from operations on nonblocking sockets that cannot be completed immediately, for example recv when no data is queued to be read from the socket. It is a nonfatal error, and the operation should be retried later. It is normal for WSAEWOULDBLOCK to be reported as the result from calling connect on a nonblocking SOCK_STREAM socket, since some time must elapse for the connection to be established.

Comment: My server seems to be up using the attached code, but I get Error 10035 when trying to connect with the client code.